# Assert import intellij

Tags: junit, automation, automated-tests, assert

I've faced with  issue, I've just cloned my project 
=> Open  project in  intellij => all import works fine except assert import

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

I have dependancies on pom file =>

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>
```

Can somebody  help me with that?
Idea throws this error "Cannot  resolve symbol "Assert" see attached screenshot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OehIT.png)

Comment: Why do you have the dependency twice? What is the problem? What errors are you seeing? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Edit description and add screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You try changing from

```
import org.junit.Assert;
```

to

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

I solved.